# How to insert data into a database in java?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to insert some data into my database. But it get me an syntaxErrorException. Can anyone tell what is the wrong of this code.

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class dbConnect {
    //Connection conn=null;
    public static Connection ConnectDB(){

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "";

        System.out.println("Connecting database...");

        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            return connection;
      //connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }        
    }



    public static void insert(String s, String t, String u, String v, String w){
        String fname, lname, tel, email, password;
        fname=s;
        lname=t;
        tel=u;
        email=v;
        password=w;

        Connection conn=ConnectDB();
        try{
            String query = "insert into customer values (null, "+fname+", "+lname+", "+tel+", "+email+", "+password+")";

      // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
      PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);


      // execute the preparedstatement
      preparedStmt.execute();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data added");

        }catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
     public static void main(String args[]) {
        //ConnectDB();
         insert("isuru", "Sandamal", "0714521589", "isurusandamalisgmail.com", "1234");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to include the stack trace in your question.

Comment: As @azurefrog notes, you need to post any and all error messages. Your not posting it suggests that you don't understand the importance of it as it will usually tell you exactly what is wrong, which usually helps you figure out how to fix things. Don't ignore it, but rather read it critically and try to figure out what it's telling you.

Comment: you have must provide the column name in qyery 

insert into customer values (null, "+fname+", "+lname+", "+tel+", "+email+", "+password+")"

must be

insert into customer(id,fnam,lname,tel,email,password) values (null, "+fname+", "+lname+", "+tel+", "+email+", "+password+")"

PLEASE CORRECT THE COLUMN NAMES

Comment: [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: Here's a quick tutorial that demonstrates [how to insert data into a database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ohOPyXZlsB0)

Answer (score 3):

You should quote string in the insert statement.

So you should change:

```
String query = "insert into customer values (null, "+fname+", "+lname+", "+tel+", "+email+", "+password+")";
```

into

```
String query = "insert into customer values (null, '"+fname+"', '"+lname+"', '"+tel+"', '"+email+"', '"+password+"')";
```

A more appropriate solution is to insert placeholder in the query string, prepare the query, and pass in the `execute` method the values of the variables. In this way you will avoid problems when those string contains single quotes (e.g. O'Connor). And more important of all, in this way you can avoid [SQL Injection Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Thank you Renzo. Now it works.